# android eclipse error creating google map

Tags: android

[2015-02-06 17:50:29 - Mmap] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED [2015-02-06 17:50:29 - Mmap] Please check logcat output for more details. How I can solve those errors ?

Comment: So what are log details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got same problem. Check your manifest file. Activity name should be prefixed with a period ".".

Comment: this is my activity name  android:name="googlemapsv2.MainActivity" it is dotted